# function in python that finds the first string can become the same as the second string by inserting or deleting a single character

Tags: python

I need to write a function in python that accepts two strings as input arguments and returns:

- 0 if the two strings match exactly.
- 1 if the first string can become the same as the second string by inserting or deleting a single character (not replacing them)
- 2 otherwise

I  did manage to do for 0 and 2, but having problems with 1.
Any ideas?

```
def single_insert_or_delete(s1,s2):
    s1lower=s1.lower()
    s2lower=s2.lower()
    str_1=list(s1lower)
    str_2=list(s2lower)
    string_1=set(str_1)
    string_2=set(str_2)
    mismatch=list(string_1.symmetric_difference(string_2))
    exact="0"
    one_change="1"
    otherwise="2"
    if s1lower==s2lower:
        return int(exact)
    elif len(mismatch)<2:
        ????????
        return int(one_change)
    else:
        return int(otherwise)

s1=input("write a word: ")
s2=input("write a word: ")
print(single_insert_or_delete(s1,s2))
```

Comment: You need to implement some edit-distance algorithm optimised to break as soon as the edit distance exceeds 1. Google Levenshtein distance and modify it accordingly.

Comment: `from difflib import SequenceMatcher` would this help? For instance `SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()` could return 0.9 if it matches extremely closely. While 0.1 would be way off

Comment: Let's keep it simple. How about iterating through both strings in parallel, and as soon there's a difference check if the two strings can be made equal by removing one of those different characters?

Comment: What do you mean by "I did manage to do for 0 and 2, but having problems with 1. Any ideas?" Because this code works for 0 and 1

Comment: is `guf==gfu==ufg etc.,.` in your case

Comment: Tim Pietzcker, I thought about that, bur cannot figure out how to put it.... I am a newbie...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def matcher(s1, s2):
    if s1 == s2:
        return 0
    elif SequenceMatcher(None, s1, s2).ratio() > 0.8: # 80% similarity-match
        return 1
    return 2
```

This would also shorten your code and give you more options.
What `SequenceMatcher` does is similarity-matching based on the [gestalt pattern matching](http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/DDJ/1988/8807/8807c/8807c.htm) algorithm which is a greedy algorithm trying to match the longest possible matches first which should benefit you.

It will return a `float` with `1.0` being a `100%` match and `0.0` being `0%`.
Fine tuning the desired `ratio()` value to match your `return 1` will be crucial, for instance setting the value threshhold to high will result in `return 2` begin executed when in fact `sink == sin` should `return 1`.

Comment: @TamaraButala That's because the ratio of that comparison would be `0.85` meaning you need to fine-tune the comparison method. This goes for any comparison that you need to do. There's different comparison methods and they're good for different things. This is a solution, it's not picture perfect but gives you an idea and something to work with.

Comment: @TamaraButala I updated my question to match anything above 80% and added a small explanation as to what the function actually does.

Comment: @TamaraButala Pleasure is all mine. Best of luck with your project! : )

Answer (score 2):

The above comments are correct - put together (you can do the case forcing)

```
import leven  

def single_insert_or_delete(s1,s2):
    if s1==s2:
        return 0
    elif leven.levenshtein(s1,s2)==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2
```

Answer (score 0):

def single_insertion_or_deletion(s1, s2):

```
if s1 == s2:
    return 0
elif len(s1) == len(s2):
    return 2

elif  len(s1) - len(s2) == 1:
    if s1[1:] == s2 or s1[:-1] == s2:
        return 1
elif len(s1) - len(s2) == -1:
    for i in range(len(s2)):
        if s1 == s2[:i] + s2[i+1:]:
            return 1
else:
    return 2
```